# How to make a count of 0 show as NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I'm making a program to check a database for transactions on 15 credit card readers.  The point of the program is to check for sales on the readers for a pre-defined date range to ensure we are not having a mechanical problem.  Generally speaking if the readers do not record a sale for a pre-defined date range then the reader should be checked for operation.  The problem is, since I'm "Counting" the number of transactions, it will come up with "0" instead of NULL, and I only want to receive an email if there are not any transactions... How do I change the count from "0" to NULL if that is the case?  My query is below:

```
SELECT        COUNT(sTerminal) AS Terminal
FROM            CC
WHERE        (dtCreated BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate) AND (sTerminal = 'Swiper 1')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 select CASE WHEN COUNT(sTerminal) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE COUNT(sTerminal) END AS Terminal
 from ....
 where ....
```

Comment: I prefer doing most of the work in the database, so I like your answer.

Comment: I agree, I find it cleaner, and easier to just have the DB run the query and then move on to C#

Answer (score 6):

If you want the count to be NULL you could do this:

```
SELECT        NULLIF(COUNT(sTerminal), 0) AS Terminal
FROM            CC
WHERE        (dtCreated BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate) AND (sTerminal = 'Swiper 1')
```

If you'd rather not return anything at all, which may be more useful, you can do a `HAVING`:

```
SELECT        COUNT(sTerminal) AS Terminal
FROM            CC
WHERE        (dtCreated BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate) AND (sTerminal = 'Swiper 1')
HAVING COUNT(sTerminal) > 0
```

Comment: `NULLIF` looks cool. I learn something new every day. Even though I try to avoid `NULL`.

Comment: @LuisSiquot I'm confused, the OP said "How do I change the count from "0" to NULL if that is the case?", which is what NULLIF should do. Did I misunderstand?

Comment: excuseme my bad +1  in fact this is better than mine becouse it returns the correct type also

Answer (score 2):

Why not handle this logic in C#:

```
var numberOfSales = GetNumberOfSales(); // Your sql will execute

if (numberOfSales > 0)
{
    SendEmails();
}
```

Comment: I suppose I could do that.  But I have no idea how to call an SQL function within C# logic... I've been using data sets and filling the info that way

Comment: I suggest you find that out - it's perfectly possible